# consolidate text in excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

[print screen in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCqEM.jpg)
I need a solution or function excel or access to get the shown result

thank you in advance

Comment: I am blinded by the speed from this question jumping to the top of the Crappy-Questions-of-the-Week list. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189139/how-to-take-formula-inputs-to-a-udf-like-conditional-formatting/43189357#43189357) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352819/concatenate-multiple-results-from-an-index-match/43352940#43352940). Take your pick.

Answer (score 5):

if the cells you want to combine is B2 and A2, type
=CONCATENATE(B2,A2)
in the cell which you want to print the combined answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big data set I would suggest you to use the following array formula:
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$30,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$30=$D3,ROW($B$1:$B$30),""),COLUMN(A1))),"")}

(Please note that you have to confirm your formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of only pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key)

The formula evaluates all the rows with the keys "text1", "text2", etc...
and returns all results of the column with the values (in the order of appearance). Please look at the Screenshot for the desired result.

[array formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C7RM.png)